# Extracting Company Organization Chart from Office365/AzureAD/ActiveDirectory

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, powerbi, office365

I am trying to find where and how I could extract the data from our company to use in Power BI.

We are using AzureAD/Office365 (synced with Active Directory) to manage our users. The data is entered so that we can see the reporting structure in our various applications.
If it is unclear what I mean, you can see the link below
[Creat Orgchart structure on Asuze AD](https://o365hq.com/blog/create-an-org-chart-from-azure-ad/)

I was hoping someone knows how the data can be retrieved and had some examples of how to collect the data.

I have found meaningful examples to do the rest of the work (e.g. [Parsing Organizational Hierarchy or Chart of Accounts in Power BI with Parent-child Functions in DAX](https://radacad.com/parsing-organizational-hierarchy-or-chart-of-accounts-in-power-bi-with-parent-child-functions-in-dax)) but I am stuck with figuring how to extract the data. Off-course I could maintain a separate chart, but it is likely that it would get off-sync and requires additional time to maintain (when employees onboard/off-board).

I have found one link explaining how to get data from Active Directory, but I believe that the information extracted in my case does not contain the data I seek.
[Active Directory hierarchy - getting all users inside a group including child groups](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/Active-Directory-hierarchy-getting-all-users-inside-a-group/td-p/492516)

I hope that someone implemented this previously and can share some code and or guidance with me. If I find a solution I'll make sure to post some code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the reference from So thread.

We can extract the data of Company Organization Chart (Upwards \ Downwards)

Up Hierarchy:

```html
GET /me/manager
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/manager
```

Also,

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=manager($levels=max;$select=id,displayName)&$select=id,displayName&$count=true

Down Hierarchy:

```html
GET /me/directReports
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/directReports
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-directreports?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http